# is there any function called crypt in C? Or i have to build that function myself?

Tags: c, function, encryption, passwords

crypt (const char *key, const char *salt)

I saw it in code, but i could not find the implementation of this function. Is it some of the conventions of C?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's specified by [`POSIX`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/crypt.html) but not by any version of the C standard. Careful though:

> The crypt() function is a string encoding function. **The algorithm is
>   implementation-defined**.

Comment: And on Linux you have to link against libcrypt in order to use it (`-lcrypt`).

Comment: so for using it i need to include unistd.h and i can use it for encrypting my string?

Comment: @user1722022 You sure can, but make sure you link against it like Nikos mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <unistd.h>
```

Don't forget to compile with

> -lcrypt

Answer (score 0):

Not C but there is a free library with it:

Here is the manual page along with some source code:

Enjoy

http://linux.die.net/man/3/crypt

http://saa.dyndns.org/stewart/Software/my_crypt.c.html